# How to display Comma separated and Fractional values in UITextfiled?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I need to format the text when the user enters text in the below mentioned desired format.

1)When the user enters **0** as the first character the text field should display the text as **0.00**

2)When the user enters **1** as the second char the text field should display as **0.01**

3)When the user enters **2** as the third char the text field should display as **0.12**

4)When the user enters **3** as the fourth char the text field should display as **1.23**

5)When the user enters **4** as the fifth char the text field should display as **12.34**

And this should continue till **7** integer digits. The highest value should be **99,99,999.00**

I have tried using number formatter but couldn't achieve this. It would be very helpful if there is any solution for this?

Apart from this i need add a **$ symbol before the text** and comma separations as well.

Comment: USE NSRegularExpression.. :)

Comment: @Downvoters can anyone explain why this question has been given so many downvotes ?

Comment: Even i couldnt understand why there were so many downvotes? Neither this question is invalid nor out of scope. I just wanted to get the solution for my problem. Can someone please justify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the UITextField to have a maximum of 7 integer digits, you'll need to validate every modification, and prevent any that result in a number with > 7 integer digits. The simplest way I know to do that is the UITextFieldDelegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string {

    NSString* modifiedFieldText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] ;
    // Remove all characters except for the digits 0 - 9.
    NSString* filteredToDigits = [modifiedFieldText stringByFilteringCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]] ;
    // Change textField's text only if the result is <= 9 digits  (7 integer digits and 2 fraction digits).
    if ( filteredToDigits.length <= 9 ) {
        // If you'd rather this method didn't change textField's text and only determined whether or not the change should proceed, you can move this code block into a method triggered by textField's Editing Changed, replacing this block with "return YES".  You'll need to once again filter textField's text to only the characters 0 - 9.
        NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new] ;
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ;

        NSNumber* asNumber = @( filteredToDigits.doubleValue / 100.0 ) ;
        textField.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:asNumber] ;
    }
    // This method just changed textField's text based on the user's input, so iOS should not also change textField's text.
    return NO ;
}
```

I used an NSString category to change @"$12,345.67" into @"1234567".

### NSString+Filter.m

```
- (NSString*) stringByRemovingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet*)charactersToRemove {
    return [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] componentsJoinedByString:@""] ;
}
- (NSString*) stringByFilteringCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet*)charactersToKeep {
    NSCharacterSet* charactersToRemove = [charactersToKeep invertedSet] ;
    return [self stringByRemovingCharactersInSet:charactersToRemove] ;
}
```

Comment: Superrr !!! Thanks a lot John.Its working wonders with the above answer.. Thanks again. Can you please up vote?

Comment: Yup, I did before I answered.